# Which lav mic would work best on a hidden camera project?

Tags: video, microphone, lavalier

Hello all,

I was wondering if anyone can help me to choose a lavalier mic that will work the best in  a hidden camera indie project.

Basically the project is to record the genuine reaction of a girl that is approached by a possible suitor.

The man will be micd up and the mic will be hidden.  Does anyone have any recommendations as to which kind of lavalier style mic to use to capture the woman's voice as clearly as possible from his mic? The interactions will be happening outside, in bars and restaurants, indoors, basically everywhere.

The sound quality does not have to be anything of production quality. This is a non income generating indie project.

I will be using the zoom H1 to record the audio and am hoping to accomplish this on a tight budget.

Thank you all, 
I look forward to your advice.

Answer (score 2):

Hey
Take a look at the [Rode PinMic](http://www.rodemic.com/mics/pinmic)
It's designed to be put through a button hole and it's really small and discreet, you could hide it using some light coloured material to match the actors costume.

I use the Rode Lavs all the time and love them, they are also reasonably priced, you should be able to plug them directly into the H1 but you need to also get this adapter [Rode Micon-2](http://www.rodemic.com/accessories/micon-2)

Hope this helps.